# Extract fully qualified class name from a String with full source code of a Java class

Tags: java

If I have the full source code of a Java class in a `String`, what is the easiest way to find its fully qualified class name?

```
public class MyParser {

   private MyParser(String code) {
      // Find here the fully qualified name of the class whose full source code 
      // is passed in the code argument.
   }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "absolute class name"? "com.example.ClassName" or something? From where do you want to lookup this? Inside the class itself?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. Isn´t it called absolute class name?

Comment: That's more called "fully qualified class name". Wouldn't that just be `System.out.println(ClassName.class.getName());` or `System.out.println(getClass().getName());` when you're not in static context? Particularly asking to achieve this triviality with regex makes your question extremely confusing.

Comment: If you're looking for a non-code solution, there should be a package <xyz>; at the top which has the com.example portion of the name.  So <xyz>.<filename> would do it.

Comment: Yes I know that ;) I´m looking for exactly that, but as a code solution.

Comment: BalusC I just edited my question to include an example.

Comment: So, does that mean that `code` contains a simple class name as a string (for example `"MyClass"`) and you want to find the fully-qualified name `"org.myprogram.MyClass"`? (Please explain your question clearly!).

Comment: code contains the whole source code of one java file

Comment: Look for package name right after `package` keyword and class name right after `class` keyword and combine them. (assuming there is only one class defined in that source).

Comment: I clarified your question. In the future please pay more attention to how you formulate the question. There was too many ambiguity in your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Use existing Java parser, such as:

http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/js/jparser.html

If you want to handle all possible cases, it will be much simpler than regexp.